# Error in Theano with tensor.zeros() and tensor.shape() as arg

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to do a simple operation of `T.zeros()` with the difference between the shapes of 2 vectors as an argument in Theano.

Something like this:

```
import theano as theano
import theano.tensor as T

x1 = T.ivector('x1')
x2 = T.ivector('x2')
shape_sub = T.sub(T.shape(x1),T.shape(x2))

zeros = T.zeros(shape_sub)

f = theano.function([x1, x2], zeros)
```

But I'm getting a value error

```
ValueError: length not known: Elemwise{sub,no_inplace} [id A] ''   
|Shape [id B] ''   
| |x1 [id C]
|Shape [id D] ''   
  |x2 [id E]
```

That's probably because the argument of T.zeros() must be a tuple or list containing the shape, not an  `ivector tensorType` containing the shapes subtracted, which is the output of shape_sub. But how am I supposed to implement this code then? I can't use `T.zeros_like()` here because it takes the whole Tensor as input, not the shape of it.

The only way I could think of solving this is by using a shared variable to the value of shape_sub, evaluating it, and then feeding to a `T.zeros()` function, but It doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of this problem is,  at compile time:

- Theano must know tensor rank.
- Theano knows nothing about exact number in tensor shape. [1]

I see it as a flaw, against static tensor shape in Tensorflow.

In your code, Theano knows `shape_sub` is a vector, but not the **length** of the vector. Thus it can't determine the rank of `zeros` call. (Actually it *should* know, however it just *forgets* that information due to internal flaws)

You can get the same error with this code:

```
shp = T.ivector()
zs = T.zeros(shp)
```

One possible solution is to hard code it:

```
x1_shp = T.shape(x1)
x2_shp = T.shape(x2)
assert x1.ndim == x2.ndim
zeros = T.zeros([x1_shp[i] - x2_shp[i] for i in range(x1.ndim)])
```

---

[1] Actually Theano knows about broadcasting dimensions, so it's possbile to tell which axes in shape has size `1`, but no more.